# Multiple Independent BTRFS Volumes

Tags: raid, btrfs

I have 4 x 2 TB drives. I want to set up one pair as a BTRFS RAID 1 volume, which I have done. I want to set up the second pair as a RAID 0 data, RAID 1 metadata volume, which I have not been able to do. It appears that the second pair get added to the first raid set, instead of being a separate volume. How do I accomplish this ?

Initially I tried this:

for the first two drives-

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs -d raid1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

The for second pair-

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs -L Non-mirror /dev/sdd /dev/sde
```

I forgot to specify a label for the raid1 set so the system assigned it one - the UUID

Comment: What commands did you use?

Comment: Edit the question, if please!

Comment: for the first two drives-
sudo mkfs.btrfs -d raid1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
The for second pair-
sudo mkfs.btrfs -L Non-mirror /dev/sdd /dev/sde
I forgot to specify a label for the raid1 set so the system assigned it one - the UUID